# ovveride variable from matlab function

Tags: matlab

I have a function

```
function func(b)


b.x = 'toto';
end
```

form another file I set b.x = 'tata'
then call func(b)

how could I ovveride b.x to use b.x = 'tata' ?
or how to check if a variable is specified from function  ?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to check if `b.x` exists, if not, set it:

```
if ~isfield(b,'x')
   b.x = 'toto';
end
```

Or you can specifically only override if the input of `b.x` is 'tata', and set it to 'toto' otherwise:

```
if ~strcmp(b.x,'tata')
   b.x = 'toto';
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are trying to do, but I would like to give some infos.
`func` doesn't have any outputs, hence the b.x = 'toto' will only be true inside the function `func`. It would be different if your function `func` was :

```
function [b] = func(b)    
    b.x = 'toto';
end
```